# Function Error in swift

Tags: function, swift

I'm trying to call a UIWebView in this in this function but it is giving me an error. How am I able to fix this error? Is there a way I can call a variable out of its function? The reason why I am doing this is because my webViewDidFinishLoad changes my height at the UIWebView. I'm trying to load a UIImage below it.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad (jobDescView : UIWebView){
        // Change the height dynamically of the UIWebView to match the html content
        var jobDescViewFrame: CGRect = jobDescView.frame
        jobDescViewFrame.size.height = 1
        jobDescView.frame = jobDescViewFrame
        var fittingSize: CGSize = (jobDescView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero))
        jobDescViewFrame.size = fittingSize
        // webViewFrame.size.width = 276; Making sure that the webView doesn't get wider than 276 px
        jobDescView.frame = jobDescViewFrame
        var jobDescViewHeight = jobDescView.frame.size.height

    }

    func bar2View (bar2View: UIImageView){
        var jobDescViewHeight = jobDescView.frame.size.height -->>ERROR unresolved identifier 'jobDescView'
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with variable scope:

Since your variable is set inside the function, you cannot access it from other functions.

Set var jobDescViewFrame as a class variable
then `jobDescViewFrame = jobDescView.frame`

```
class MyClass : OptionalSuperClass, OptionalProtocol1 {
var jobDescViewHeight:CGFloat!

func webViewDidFinished(jobDescView:UIWebView){
    jobDescViewFrame = jobDescView.frame
}

func bar2View (bar2View: UIImageView){
    jobDescViewHeight = jobDescView.frame.size.height '
}
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So set a variable in a class at the beginning of the project or just in that function? If so how would you set a class variable?

Comment: okay I tried this and its giving me an error saying undeclared type OptionalSuperClass, jobDescViewFrame and jobDescView.

Comment: Those are optional. I don't know how your class is setup and what you are inheriting from.

Comment: Thank you I was able to figure some of it by this!